# How to limit the number of lines / text rows with Rails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to limit the number of lines / text rows in a type `text` attribute in Rails?

I know that I can limit the number of characters like so:

```
validates :message, :length => { :maximum => 100 }
```

But how about the number of lines?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any limit for the length of a line??

Comment: Not yet. It would be nice to restrict that too, though.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: Yes, both work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a custom validation to do this is pretty easy. You use `validate` (not `validates`) to do this:

```
validate :not_too_many_lines
private
def not_too_many_lines
  if self.message.split("\n").length > 10
    self.errors.add :message, "has too many lines"
  end
end
```

Under the hood this runs before `valid?`, which checks to see whether `errors` has anything in it. If you then ran `<record>.errors.full_messages` after trying to save an invalid record you'd see "Message has too many lines". If you just want it to say "too many lines" you can use `self.errors.add :base, "too many lines"`

Answer (score 4):

You could create a custom validator to implement the required logic. Something along the following idea should do the trick:

```
class LinesValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    lines = value.split("\n")

    if lines.size > options[:maximum]
      record.errors[attribute] << "too many lines"
    end

    if lines.any? { |l| l.size > options[:length]}
      record.errors[attribute] << "line longer than allowed length"
    end
  end

end
```

And the usage could be as follows:

```
validates :message, lines: { maximum: 5, length: 10}
```

For more information regarding validations and custom validators, you can read the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet.

So to add top the answer, split('\n') is not always safe.
Better just use `String#lines`

Here is the example with the `lines` method instead.

```
validate :not_too_many_lines
private
def not_too_many_lines
  if self.message.lines.count > 10
    errors.add :message, "has too many lines"
  end
end
```